# compare different Imputation method by RMSE

Tags: r, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, rms, mice

My original dataset :

```
     dforg=data.frame(x=c(1,4,6,5,7,8,9,10,4,3),
                  y=c(10,12,13,18,14,18,20,15,12,17),
                  z=c(225,198,520,147,157,130,107,200,87,99),
                  v=c(44,51,74,89,45,55,25,36,75,25))
> dforg
    x  y   z  v
1   1 10 225 44
2   4 12 198 51
3   6 13 520 74
4   5 18 147 89
5   7 14 157 45
6   8 18 130 55
7   9 20 107 25
8  10 15 200 36
9   4 12  87 75
10  3 17  99 25
```

I  randomly created the following incomplete dataset :

```
    dfmiss=data.frame(x=c(1,4,6,NA,7,NA,9,10,4,3),
      y=c(10,12,NA,NA,14,18,20,15,12,17),
      z=c(225,198,520,147,NA,130,NA,200,NA,99),
      v=c(44,51,74,89,45,55,25,36,75,25))

     dfmiss
    x  y  z  v  
1   1 10 225 44
2   4 12 198 51
3   6 NA 520 74
4  NA NA 147 89
5   7 14  NA 45
6  NA 18 130 55
7   9 20  NA 25
8  10 15 200 36
9   4 12  NA 75
10  3 17  99 25
```

I used three different types of imputation such as :

1-Mean imputation

```
    library("imputeR")
    meanimp=guess(dfmiss,type="mean")
    meanimp
         x     y   z  v
 [1,]  1.0 10.00 225 44
 [2,]  4.0 12.00 198 51
 [3,]  6.0 14.75 520 74
 [4,]  5.5 14.75 147 89
 [5,]  7.0 14.00 217 45
 [6,]  5.5 18.00 130 55
 [7,]  9.0 20.00 217 25
 [8,] 10.0 15.00 200 36
 [9,]  4.0 12.00 217 75
[10,]  3.0 17.00  99 25
```

I used RMSE to know the accuracy of imputation as follows :

```
    library("imputeR")
   Rmse( meanimp,dfmiss,dforg,norm=T) `# RMSE for mean imputation` 
    [1] 1.128382
```

2-KNN imputation

```
library("DMwR")
knnimp= knnImputation(dfmiss, 3) # k=3
 knnimp
           x        y        z  v
1   1.000000 10.00000 225.0000 44
2   4.000000 12.00000 198.0000 51
3   6.000000 12.16743 520.0000 74
4   4.422397 12.05266 147.0000 89
5   7.000000 14.00000 178.9235 45
6   6.021133 18.00000 130.0000 55
7   9.000000 20.00000 167.5088 25
8  10.000000 15.00000 200.0000 36
9   4.000000 12.00000 194.4462 75
10  3.000000 17.00000  99.0000 25

Rmse( knnimp,dfmiss,dforg,norm=T)
[1] 0.7834937
```

3-MICE imputation (multiple imputation by chained equation)

```
library("mice")
miceimp=mice(dfmiss,m=5) # m=5 is number of imputation 
complete(miceimp,"long")

   .imp .id  x  y   z  v
1     1   1  1 10 225 44
2     1   2  4 12 198 51
3     1   3  6 10 520 74
4     1   4  3 10 147 89
5     1   5  7 14 225 45
6     1   6  9 18 130 55
7     1   7  9 20 225 25
8     1   8 10 15 200 36
9     1   9  4 12 225 75
10    1  10  3 17  99 25
11    2   1  1 10 225 44
12    2   2  4 12 198 51
13    2   3  6 14 520 74
14    2   4 10 14 147 89
15    2   5  7 14 130 45
16    2   6  9 18 130 55
17    2   7  9 20 130 25
18    2   8 10 15 200 36
19    2   9  4 12 520 75
20    2  10  3 17  99 25
21    3   1  1 10 225 44
22    3   2  4 12 198 51
23    3   3  6 18 520 74
24    3   4  7 12 147 89
25    3   5  7 14 130 45
26    3   6  7 18 130 55
27    3   7  9 20 198 25
28    3   8 10 15 200 36
29    3   9  4 12 225 75
30    3  10  3 17  99 25
31    4   1  1 10 225 44
32    4   2  4 12 198 51
33    4   3  6 12 520 74
34    4   4  6 17 147 89
35    4   5  7 14 225 45
36    4   6  4 18 130 55
37    4   7  9 20 225 25
38    4   8 10 15 200 36
39    4   9  4 12 147 75
40    4  10  3 17  99 25
41    5   1  1 10 225 44
42    5   2  4 12 198 51
43    5   3  6 10 520 74
44    5   4  3 14 147 89
45    5   5  7 14 200 45
46    5   6 10 18 130 55
47    5   7  9 20 198 25
48    5   8 10 15 200 36
49    5   9  4 12 225 75
50    5  10  3 17  99 25
```

**My question is that in multiple imputation I have 5 complete dataset or more  due to number of m (`miceimp=mice(dfmiss,m=5) # m=5 is number of imputation` )
how to calculate RMSE for mice since I have 5 complete dataset because I want to compare the accuracy  of mice to mean and knn imputation .**
thanks for help

Comment: I see that imputeR has been removed from CRAN, so I do not know what Rmse does. With that in mind, is there any reason to think that a lower RMSE is better for an imputation? Remember that with multiple imputations, we want our imputations to capture the **uncertainty** of our missing values, *not* to be the "best" estimate for our missing values.

Comment: @CliffAB I used imputeR you must install it (`install.packages("imputeR")`) , I read many articles they used RMSE to compare their imputations result        thanks for ur comment .

Comment: At this time, imputeR is [currently unavailable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeR/index.html)

Comment: @CliffAB , however I installed it to R library and I can use it know .                    but could you tell me why they unavailable it from CRAN  ?